# Run WPF application with custom command parameters from command prompt

Tags: wpf, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I want to run wpf application with custom parameters in command prompt, basically this is achieve with no gui, if i don't run from command prompt, it should show gui!

Answer (score 3):

Do this-

1) Add event -> Startup="App_Startup" to App.Xaml

2) Add Event handler for "App_Startup" to App.Xaml.cs

3) In "App_Startup" you can check command params this way-

```
     if (e.Args.Length == 0)
        {
            MainWindow m = new MainWindow();
            m.Show();
        }
```

4) Remove StartupUri from App.Xaml

This way WPF GUI will appear only if there is no command args.